# Converting standard error to sampling variance for meta-analysis

Tags: variance, standard-error, meta-analysis

Is it possible to get sampling variance (vi) from a standard error for meta-analysis.

Specifically, I am unable to obtain raw data from the computation of an SMD. However, the SMD and confidence intervals are available, so I can compute the approximate Standard Error (upper bound - lower bound)/3.92.

However is it possible to convert this to a sampling variance? I have been able to create effect sizes using 'escalc' function in 'metafor', so I have yi and vi.

Comment: I have the feeling that I completely miss your point but why not square the se?

Comment: Yes - thanks. I believe I was overthinking things

Comment: For sampling variance, don't you have to take into account the size of the sample. Would it be SE^2 * n ?